# How can I finish editing a commit message with Sublime Text?

Tags: git, sublimetext

I configured Sublime Text as my Git commit editor. When I do `git commit` Sublime opens and I write the commit message and then I save the file and close it, but in the git terminal it is still stuck in the git commit, and didn't return the console to me!.

How do I return to the console after editing with Sublime?

Answer (score 11):

I think you need `-w`.
Try setting Sublime as the editor for git with

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -w"
```

This will wait with returning until you actually close the file, which will work better for git.

You may also want to use `-n`, which will start a new Sublime window for your commit message so that when you close it, the files you were working on are unaffected (you don't have to close your main editor window):

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -w -n"
```

Or on Windows, something like

```
git config --global core.editor "'c:/program files/sublime text 3/sublime_text.exe' -w -n"
```

I think it's not possible to do it upon closing the tab in a multi-tab window though, at least not trivially.

Comment: I used this command with the -w option `git config --global core.editor "'c:/program files/sublime text 3/sublime_text.exe' -w"` and now git completes the commit and return to the console only when I close all of sublime, I want to be able to close only the tab that has the message and not all the program, I use sublime to edit my project and I don't want to be opening and closing all tabs.

Comment: Try with `-w -n` instead of just `-w`. That way it will be in a new window and will not affect your project when you close that.

Comment: it now opens a new tab, but the previous problem persists. git still doesn't return to the console unless I close all of sublime tabs.

Comment: i am haveing the same problem, Did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after making sublime my editor with -n (new window) -w (wait) options. What worked for me was making sure they are both running with the same privileges i.e. if shell is running elevated then sublime has to be elevated and vice versa if shell isn't elevated then sublime shouldn't be elevated.

Answer (score 0):

from Sublime Text 3 Command Palette (Ctrl-shift-p), I go to the Commit (git: Commit), type in the text and do a Ctrl-w to save and close it.